# Triggering audio hover effects in plotly

Tags: python, matlab, plotly

I recently discovered `plotly` and I think it's a great tool to share interactive plots over the internet. Since my research is in audio signal processing, I'd like to use it to convert my matlab/python plots into interactive plots allowing the user to play the different audio signals used to generate the plot.

For instance, if a bar plot shows a bunch of bars corresponding to as many different speech enhancement strategies, I'd like to find a way to play the different audio signals when hovering on the different lines.

I found [this example](https://plot.ly/matlab/hover-events/) (or [here](https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/aOPGYm), to open it with codePen) to add custom hover effects to a `plotly` plot; specifically, the example deals with showing an image when hovering over a bar of the plot. I'd like to have something similar, but triggering an audio playback instead of an image visualization.

How could the code be edited to do this? (e.g. to play a [given sound](http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1137&type=wav) when hovering over one of the bars)

Comment: Any luck with it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Nope. I realized it would take too much time to get to properly understand it so, for the moment being, I put it aside :/

Answer (score 3):

I see following approaches which can work for such visualization:

1. There is an ability to build own components with **dash**. Here is a tutorial: [react-for-python-developers](https://dash.plot.ly/react-for-python-developers) and [cookiecutter generator](https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate). As an example here you can find a component with wrapped [react-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound): [dash_audio_components](https://github.com/tracek/dash_audio_components).
   It can be installed and used in "dash"-generated web interface for **plotly** by the following way:

   `import dash
   import dash_audio_components
   import dash_core_components
   app = dash.Dash('app-name')
   ...Set serving locally because this component isn't placed to cdn
   app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
   app.layout = html.Div(
       children=[
           dcc.Graph(
               id='chart-id',
               figure=<FigureObj>
           ),
           dash_audio_components.DashAudioComponents(
               id='audio-player',
               url=None,
               playStatus='STOPPED'
           )
       ]
   )
   @app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('audio-player', 'playStatus'), 
                 [dash.dependencies.Input('chart-id', 'clickData')])
   def set_status(click_data):
       ...Preserve somewhere status of audio-player and return changed state
       ...hover or unhover events can be handled as well
   @app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('audio-player', 'url'), 
                 [dash.dependencies.Input('chart-id', 'clickData')])
   def set_status(click_data):
       ...Return url from textual information received from click_data`

This article describes good practices of sharing some state: [Sharing data between callbacks](https://dash.plot.ly/sharing-data-between-callbacks)

2. Another way which can be more applicable for those who
   experienced with web development is implementing a separate SPA with [react-plotly](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/) and passing data to it from service endpoints, here is how you can bind sounds to existing "plotly" click event [binding to click events](https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/#binding-to-click-events), it can be done on componentDidMount method call or in JSX as callback with "plotly_click" or "plotly_hover" property. There are plenties of React components to play audios. Application blueprint can be generated by 'yeoman' as well for simplicity sake. Codepen example with plotly.js library to handle 'clicks' and 'unhover' events and play sound: [codepen plotly](https://codepen.io/yavalvas/pen/REyraJ)

Comment: Wow! I was thinking this thread had been forgotten :)
Thanks for the help. I'll take a look and see if I can (or I am able to) apply your suggestions ;)

Cheers

Comment: @gbernardi you are welcome, I can add clarifications if any are needed.

Comment: Hi, the audio component looks promising. But it seems to me the input has to be an url of mp3 or wav. I wonder if there is any workaround for that, as I am working with a numpy array, and hover on the data on a scatter plot would index the corresponding row of the array which is then converted to audio playback.

Comment: Hi. I know only two ways, in a browser it can be converted to an audio element to be played after that or it can be buffered/stored as blob and played. I believe Blob format can be passed as src string to the dash component. You can have both array and converted in advance wav recordings as a workaround for scatter plot.
In another way you can use blob format to preserve audio buffer data and play it without dash component, here is one tutorial:
https://medium.com/@bryanjenningz/how-to-record-and-play-audio-in-javascript-faa1b2b3e49b